# Trying to Start React-native with Expo - Tried to register two views with same name RNSVGRect

Tags: react-native, expo, decentralized-applications

I was trying to build a React-native dapp using the starter template provided by

```
npx create-react-native-dapp
```

I tried to run it, works fine in the web but when scanning the Expo QR it throws an error

> Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNSVGRect.

[image: RNSVGRect Error]

Answer (score 0):

**Try This **
*Expo managed apps now require you to install react-native-svg using*

> expo install react-native-svg

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Svg, { Circle, Rect } from 'react-native-svg';

export default class SvgExample extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, { alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }]}>
        <Svg height="50%" width="50%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <Circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="blue" strokeWidth="2.5" fill="green" />
          <Rect x="15" y="15" width="70" height="70" stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" fill="yellow" />
        </Svg>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```